# How do you intercept the page requests in Wordpress?

Tags: permalinks

I am working with Wordpress 4.1.

I am building a custom template that won't be using Wordpress pages.

I would still like Wordpress to use permalinks like 'www.website.com/{page_name}/{something else}'. However, instead of looking for pages in it's own list of pages, I would like WP to send the 'page name' to my code and let it dispatch the rest of the queary.

I looked at the action and filter hooks, but nothing jumped out as a place to intercept the system.

Is it possible to do this in Wordpress? If so, how can I implement it?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are looking for `locate_template` in conjuction with the `template_include` hook to set your own template for a particular page

Comment: Looks like 'template_redirect' is the one. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Pieter Goosen

Comment: My pleasure. Just a note, do not change templates on `template_redirect`, do it on `template_include` which is the more correct way to include a custom template to use. Enjoy :-)

Comment: I spoke too soon. I think this has to be done with the .htaccess file. When I implemented template_redirect and tried to type in something like 'www.mysite.com/test_page' the server returned a 404. It makes perfect sense too now that I think about it. :)

Comment: Ok, then I did misunderstood the question :-)

Comment: Could you please clarify - are you looking to change the URL as well as the template? For example **www.mysite.com/my-page** would typically use the template **page.php** - are you looking to keep the URL but use a custom template (such as **my-custom-page.php**), or to change the URL as well?

Comment: Okie. I spoke too soon again Pieter. It occurred to me, last night when I was contemplating this problem over some cold beers, that I had the permalinks set-up incorrectly for this type of format. Once I changed the permalink to include a post name, the 404 error disappeared and it went through to my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## template_include

Your first option here is to change the template that is used your pages so that you can do anything you wish, once that template has been called.

The example below checks that the page is called 'portfolio', but obviously you can insert your own checks, and then locates a template called 'my-template-page.php'.  If that template doesn't exist you are just shown the original template.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_custom_page_template', 99 );
function my_custom_page_template( $template ) {

    if ( is_page( 'portfolio' )  ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'my-template-page.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

---

## template_redirect

You can also redirect the user to another page, again allowing you to do anything that you want but this time with the added bonus of being able to change the URL. Personally I've only every used this hook when I'm forcing people to log in before viewing a page and would suggest `templage_include`, but if you have your reasons then fair enough.

In conjunction with this code you would need a template `page-my-template-example.php` as well as a page called 'My Template Example'.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_redirect_to_template_page' );
function my_redirect_to_template_page(){

    if( is_page( 'goodies' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/my-template-page/' ) );
        exit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much the same solution I came up with. One note: To do this, the permalinks have to be set-up for the desired format.